# How to set up a .NET development environment for SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

We need to migrate some things from several on-prem systems into SharePoint Online.

I'd like to use C#.NET because ideally, we would then be able to re-use code written for on-prem SharePoint.

On-prem SharePoint code I've used in the past uses references like this:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

And connects to SharePoint like this:

```
// Connect to SharePoint
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://SiteURL/");
SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
// Connect to lists
foreach (SPList l in web.Lists)
...
```

We no longer have on-prem SharePoint.

What would we need to have on our dev machine so that we can use our code to access SharePoint online?

Comment: It's the same product (or near enough, anyway), just at a different URL. Have you tried just changing the URL in your code to point at your online version?

Comment: That would have been good to try, but no, I can't really try it since I don't actually have the referenced DLLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Online does not expose Server side SDK (SSOM), so you canot use above code or reference `Microsoft.SharePoint`. The available options for SPO connection are:

- CSOM
- JSOM
- Rest API

More References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code#basic-operations-with-the-sharepoint-net-client-object-model
- https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/connect-to-sharepoint-online-on-premise-and-extranet-using-csom

BR

Comment: Thanks for that.  I think CSOM is what I'm looking for.  Where do you get those DLLs to reference if you don't have a SharePoint server?

Comment: just get it from NuGet package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM/   OR  https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/